# How to construct a QueryBuilder that carries an array of filters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I wish to convert the following query to an object of type `QueryBuilder`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": { "field1": "val1"}},
        { "range": {
          "field2": {"lte": val}}

        },
        {"nested": {
          "path": "field3",
          "score_mode": "none",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {"term": {"field3.key": "foo"}},
                {"term": {"field3.val": "bar"}}
              ]
            }
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the `filter` key in both instances actually carries an array of queries.

My Google-fu has failed me so far. How do I go about building this object? Is it as simple as creating a `BoolQueryBuilder` object and invoking the `filter` method three times on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you start creating object from the inner search object outwards for example  :

```
var innerSearch = new BoolQueryBuilder();
innerSearch.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field3.key", "foo" ));
innerSearch.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("field3. val", "bar" ));
```

now you add that inner search to an outer search, and in your case the inner search is a nested object

```
NestedQueryBuilder nestedQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("field3",innerSearch, ScoreMode.None);


var outerSearch = new BoolQueryBuilder();
outerSearch.filter(nestedQueryBuilder)
```

Comment: Roger. A follow-up on the first fragment that you provide: it's `innerSearch.filter` instead of `innerSearch.must` correct?